# Aplicar Estilo Tooltip de Bootstrap a DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, php7, php5

En un datatable visualizo información extraída de una base de datos, en ciertas filas agrego una etiqueta `span` a la cual le pongo los atributos necesarios para aplicar el estilo **tooltip** de **bootstrap**, el problema es que el estilo del **tooltip** no lo esta aplicando.

Mi código script:

```
function declararDataTable()
{
    var mes = $("#mesVal").val();
    var ano = $("#anoVal").val();

    tabla_notas = $('#notas').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ tickets por página",
                "sZeroRecords": "No existen tickets",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ tickets",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 tickets",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Encontrados de _MAX_ tickets)"
        },
        "aoColumns": [{"sWidth":"10%"},{"sWidth":"10%"},{"sWidth":"15%"},{"sWidth":"15%"}
                     ,{"sWidth":"15%"},{"sWidth":"10%"},{"sWidth":"10%"},{"sWidth":"15%"}],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../includes/acciones/control_nota/get_notas_json.php',
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "mes", "value": mes });
            aoData.push({ "name": "ano", "value": ano });
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 25
    });

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

Mi html:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <label>Año:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="anoVal" onChange="obtenerNotas();">
    <?php
      for($i = 2018; $i <= date("Y"); $i++)
      {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Mes:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="mesVal" onChange="obtenerNotas();">
    <?php
      for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
      {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo getMes($i); ?></option>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<hr class="limpiar">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="notas" style="width: 100%;">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Ticket</th>
     <th>Fecha</th>
     <th>Cliente</th>
     <th>Ubicación</th>
     <th>Artículo</th>
     <th>Monto</th>
     <th>Tipo</th>
     <th>Repartidor</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Código `get_notas_json.php`:

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Nota.php");

extract($_GET);
# mes
# ano

// se realizan procesos para obtener los valores de $fecha_inicio y $fecha_fin tomando en cuenta las variables mes y ano 

$notas = Nota::getLista($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin);

$json = array();

if(is_array($notas))
{
    foreach($notas as $nota)
    {
        $fecha = explode("-", $nota["fecha"], 3);
        $fecha = $fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0];

        $oNota = new Nota($nota["id_nota"]);
        $no_articulos = Nota::getNumArticulos($nota["folio"]);
        $articulos = $oNota->getArticulos();

        $temp = array();
        array_push($temp, str_pad($nota["folio"], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
        array_push($temp, $fecha);
        array_push($temp, $nota["cliente"]);             
        array_push($temp, $nota["ubicacion"]);

        if($no_articulos == 1)
        {
            array_push($temp, $articulos[0]["articulo"]);
            array_push($temp, "$".number_format($articulos[0]["monto"], 2));
        }
        else
        {
            $monto = 0;

            $item = "";

            foreach($articulos as $articulo)
            {
                $monto += $articulo["monto"];

                if($item == "")
                 $item = $articulo['articulo']."<br>";
                else
                 $item = $item.$articulo['articulo']."<br>";
            }

            $lista = $articulos[0]["articulo"]."<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-original-title='".$item."' 
                        data-html='true' style='color: #FF0000; cursor: pointer;'>*</span>";

            array_push($temp, $lista);
            array_push($temp, "$".number_format($monto, 2));
        }

        if($nota["pago"] == 1)
          array_push($temp, "Efectivo");
        else
          array_push($temp, "Crédito");

        array_push($temp, $nota["distribuidor"]);

        array_push($json, $temp);
    }
}

echo json_encode(array("aaData" => $json));
?>
```

¿Como podría solucionar esto?

He investigando y me di cuenta de algo, cuando ejecuto este código `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` desde la consola si lo aplica y por que desde el archivo que tiene el código no??